# Open unique Google Sheet based on parameter value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to paste certain data into 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2' and 'Sheet3'. However, there's only condition, if 'kombi' is value 1, then I want to open Sheet1 and paste data in there, if 'kombi' is value 2, I want to open Sheet2 and paste data there.. The problem is, I get the correct parameters, but it only paste data into Sheet1, even if kombi is other value. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, here's code:

[image]

```
function doGet(request) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bqe_p7pDHTxpIpm4sOKKirtYMAhGP47k8hZkczHhzpE");
  var result = {"status": "SUCCESS"};

  /*function jumpByActive(){
  var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  spreadsheet.toast('jumped by active sheet');
  }*/

  try {
    var ime_ekipe = request.parameter.ime_ekipe;
    var ime_stranke = request.parameter.ime_stranke;
    var postna_stevilka = request.parameter.postna_stevilka;
    var teza = request.parameter.teza;
    var type = request.parameter.type;
    var datum = request.parameter.datum;
    var dostavljeno = request.parameter.dostavljeno;
    var kombi = request.parameter.kombi;

    if (kombi == "1") {
      var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      var rowData = sheet.appendRow([ime_ekipe,ime_stranke,postna_stevilka,teza, type, datum, dostavljeno, kombi]);
      
    }else if (kombi == "2") {
      var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      var rowData = sheet.appendRow([ime_ekipe,ime_stranke,postna_stevilka,teza, type, datum, dostavljeno, kombi]);

    }else {
      var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      var rowData = sheet.appendRow([ime_ekipe,ime_stranke,postna_stevilka,teza, type, datum, dostavljeno, kombi]);
    };

  }catch(exc){

    result = {"status" : "FAILED", "message": exc};

  }

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with `var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheetByName("sheetname");`

Answer (score 0):

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//You should check this because you have a lot of query parameters.  Perhaps you have too many
  var result = { "status": "SUCCESS" };
  try {
    var ime_ekipe = e.parameter.ime_ekipe;
    var ime_stranke = e.parameter.ime_stranke;
    var postna_stevilka = e.parameter.postna_stevilka;
    var teza = e.parameter.teza;
    var type = e.parameter.type;
    var datum = e.parameter.datum;
    var dostavljeno = e.parameter.dostavljeno;
    var kombi = e.parameter.kombi;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet' + kombi);
    sheet.appendRow([ime_ekipe, ime_stranke, postna_stevilka, teza, type, datum, dostavljeno, kombi]);
  } catch (exc) {
    result = { "status": "FAILED", "message": exc };
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Did you deploy your webapp?

Comment: Yes I deployed, I'm getting returned 'null' value